# Google Glass First App Security

Tags: google-gdk, google-mirror-api

We are creating our first google glass app and I had some security questions that came up that I can't seem to find a definitive answer to on the web. They are as follows:

1. What apps are available for us to be able to wipe the glass (factory reset) remotely if they are ever misplaced or lost?
2. Is there an app or a way to automatically wipe the glass maybe at a certain time everyday of the data that is one them?
3. When we do a factory reset, is the data securely wiped from the device? Or like a PC is the data still there for possible usage if the device memory is hacked into directly?
4. If we pass data over the network, is it passed using some sort of encryption currently? Or do we have to take this into account when developing our app?
5. Is there a way to allow multiple people to use the device without having to wipe the device and setup with another account? The only way we were able to login using 2 different accounts was for the first person to factory reset it and allow the next person to login using their account. What we were envisioning was a way for the device to securely authenticate and allow multiple users to use it differently somehow without having to reset it.
6. The only current way to lock the device that I found is to create the swipe/tap pattern that is included. Are there any apps that allow for a more secure type of login?

If anyone can help on any of the questions, that would help out a lot.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

1. The MyGlass webapp and mobile app allow you to do a remote device reset. From the mobile app, you can go to *Settings* while the webapp does it from the *MyGlass -> Device Info* page.
2. There is no way to do an automatic reset every day that I'm aware of. What are you trying to do here? Just reset it to a known state every day for development?
3. At this time, you probably can't count on it being a secure reset.
4. This is a pretty vague question. Google hasn't provided details on the sharing protocol, but it is a safe bet that this is done using SSL on some level. From their servers to yours using the Mirror API must be done using HTTPS. Of course, if you're doing the network data passing yourself, then it's up to you.
5. No, this isn't possible at this time. Glass is a **very** personal device. More so than phones, and most phones don't have a profile feature!
6. I'm not aware of any, but I'm not sure how much more secure you can get and still be usable. Can you elaborate on what you're envisioning?

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the response. Our app is a school project and we were just wondering about the security aspects of storing, passing over the network, and securing the data on the glass. We wanted to at least get the basic security information to help us design the app and what types of data we could feel comfortable using in our app. We may deal with confidential information during the project and were trying to think the best way to protect it. It may turn into something bigger if we can implement it correctly. These answers helped a lot though. Thanks a lot! More questions to come :)